# Writing a significant figure

Tags: siunitx

How can I write this significant figure
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\MyData
\readarray{MyData}{ 0.0000000000000000000072 }

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = E,round-mode = figures, round-precision = 1,
  scientific-notation = true}

\begin{document}

\checkMyData(1)
\num{\cachedata}


\end{document}
```

but it gave me that this not found.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: I get “7E–21“ with the given code. I get “7.2E–21” if `round-precision` is set to 2. Possibly unrelated, but do you *really* need `arrayjobx`?

Comment: And `exponent-product = \times` (instead of `output-exponent-marker`) in addition to @egreg's comment gets you the `×`. If you get an error message, something else is wrong. I don't get any error message.

Comment: I got it with exponent-product = \times but without = E. Thank you so much guys